# Adding Elements to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, lwjgl

I tried to write a class wich should create a cylinder. But when I try to draw my `ArrayList` there are 180 Objects with the same Value in it. I don't understand what's wrong in there when I try to add the Quads to my `ArrayList`.

```
public class Planet {
    public static ArrayList<Quad> createRing(int x, int y, int z, int radius) {
        ArrayList<Quad> quads = new ArrayList<Quad>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
            float x1 = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * radius);
            float y1 = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) * radius);
            i++;
            float x2 = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * radius);
            float y2 = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) * radius);

            quads.add(new Quad(new Vector3f(x1, y1, 4), new Vector3f(x2, y2, 4), new Vector3f(x2, y2, 0),
                    new Vector3f(x1, y1, 0)));
        }
        return quads;
    }
}

----QUAD.java

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Quad {
//have to be non-static
static Vector3f Cord1; 
static Vector3f Cord2;
static Vector3f Cord3;
static Vector3f Cord4;
//have to be non-static
public Quad(Vector3f cord1,Vector3f cord2,Vector3f cord3,Vector3f cord4) {
Cord1 = cord1;
Cord2 = cord2;
Cord3 = cord3;
Cord4 = cord4;
}
public void draw() {
//GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
GL11.glVertex3f(Cord1.x, Cord1.y, Cord1.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(Cord2.x, Cord2.y, Cord2.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(Cord3.x, Cord3.y, Cord3.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(Cord4.x, Cord4.y, Cord4.z);
}
public void out() {

System.out.println(Cord1.x+" "+ Cord1.y+" "+ Cord1.z);
System.out.println(Cord2.x+" "+ Cord2.y+" "+ Cord2.z);
System.out.println(Cord3.x+" "+ Cord3.y+" "+ Cord3.z);
System.out.println(Cord4.x+" "+ Cord4.y+" "+ Cord4.z);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try `System.out.println(eins); System.out.println(zwei);` etc. and check if they are the same? Are you sure you're assigning different values each time?

Comment: I tested that by changing the Value in the for loop and everytime i draw i got an other Part of my cylinder. But i cant draw the whole cylinder at once.

Comment: Is `Quad` a class you've defined? Are its members `static`? Please add the code for that class. (If they are static, make them non-static).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Quad {
static Vector3f Cord1;
static Vector3f Cord2;
static Vector3f Cord3;
static Vector3f Cord4;
public Quad(Vector3f cord1,Vector3f cord2,Vector3f cord3,Vector3f cord4) {
Cord1 = cord1;
Cord2 = cord2;
Cord3 = cord3;
Cord4 = cord4;
}
```

You have made the `CordN` variables `static`, so each field has just 1 value, shared between all instances of the class. As such, each time you create a new instance of the class, the previous values are overwritten.

Remove the `static` modifier.

---

Also, note that it's good practice to make member variables `final` unless you absolutely need them not to be. That does not appear to be the case here, so make them `final` - and this would have caught your issue automatically, because you wouldn't be able to reassign a `static final` field in the constructor.